# Django template create div.selector boxs

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I`m working with Django 1.9 and in the admin section I saw the following structure:

[image]

I want to implement a selector like this in my template for form- two boxes, the left one in filled with some class objects. The right one is empty and when I click on the arrows between the boxes- the items move accordingly. Finally in the form I want to be able do something with the chosen items in the right box.

I searched for "html selector" but without any good results. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a direct solution.

I used Django admin widgets as following.

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import FilteredSelectMultiple
class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = A
    fields = (
        'name', 'nickname', )
    widgets = {
        "name": FilteredSelectMultiple("name", is_stacked=False),
        "nickname": FilteredSelectMultiple("nickname", is_stacked=False),
    }
```

a_template.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/jsi18n/"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/actions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/urlify.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/prepopulate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectBox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/admin/js/SelectFilter2.js"></script>

<form role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's one way to go about it, as long as you are using Django.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you don't have a *direct solution* to the above hence you didn't find one directly.

One of the possible solution that i can think of is through **frontend manipulations using Javascript**. Here's what you can do:

Have two different ***divs*** in your html, say "left-box" and "right-box". Now in your ***views.py*** you return a list of items you want to display in the left box and then in the ***html*** file you display them in the left box.

Now comes the important part.
The list you have displayed in the left box has to be a **check box input type** (so that individual item can be selected/checked or deselected/unchecked) or any other **selection type of input**.

Now you have your **two buttons** between the left and the right box.
So you'll write the **on-click functions** for these two buttons in your javascript file.

For the right-arrow button, the on-click function will **detect all the selected items** from the left box, will **hide/remove** them from the left box and **add** them to the right box i.e., you'll have to create all your divs, li,  checkbox input from javascript.

Similarly for the left-arrow button, the on-click function will detect all the selected items from the right box, will hide/remove them from the right box and add them to the left box.

And then there will be eventually be a Save button at the bottom which will submit this data by either GET or POST. But as you want all the data to be submitted on a single click of SAVE at the bottom of the page, it means that **both the left and right box will be under a single FORM**. Hence u'll need to have a common "name" attribute say "left-input" for the left box items and "right-input" for the right box items as only the "name" and "value" pair are submitted in any html form.

So in your views when you'll request.GET or POST, you'll get a **multi-valued dictionary** of only two keys("left-input" and "right-input") having a list of values each.

And then you can convert the querydict to a python dict and do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Templates are the easiest and can be arranged in no time...  :p

Comment: No... that is why I posted this question. It goes view -> form -> template.html + javascript. so....

Comment: Got it.. So is that form part in views->form->template.html a necessary requirement for you?? i mean one can anyday have views->template.html(contains html form).
Though you can still use views->form->template.html and append and remove items from the form using javascript so that you are able to use form-cleaned-data in your views, but for that also you'll have to write html froms with same id values of input as that in forms.py which will complicate things.

Comment: How do I do views->template.html(contains html form)??? I learn Django from the official website. Can you help me?

Comment: Yea, its pretty easy. In your views.py you'll write a class based view and your class will be of TemplateView type.
This is one of my web-app's views.py -> https://github.com/ankushrgv/notification/blob/master/apps/notifications/views.py
Rest you can check the official django documentation of TemplateView for better understanding -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview